# How do you say "Kiss me" in Russian?

Tags: словарь

How do you say "Kiss me" to a man in Russian? I ask this because I've seen that some phrases change if you say it to a woman or a man, so I'd like to know how can a woman say "kiss me" to a man.

Answer (score 3):

А woman can either say (timidly)

Поцелуй меня.

Or more demanding

Целуй меня, целуй!

I wouldn't say it somehow differs with men. There is an old song Вдоль по Питерской, where the man sings

Поцелуй же меня, кума-душечка! Ну поцелуй!

But let them speak for themselves.

Comment: Worth noting that due to the "imperative mood" (*повелительное наклонение*) there is no gender difference here. It remains the same no matter whether it is addressed to a man or a woman.

Comment: Could a downvoter explain their action? Some people never learn that it is impolite.